# Multiplex multiple mobile broadband connections into one access point

Tags: wifi, router, multiplexing, broadband

I'm trying to find a way to take multiple mobile broadband connections, and bridge them together to expose one wifi access point.

I want to tether the phone's broadband, and multiplex the data.

How can this be achieved? Is there a router, that has multiple wifi's that can be used to connect to the phones?

Will I need to write a script to manage the data? Or is there something out there?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a little more complicated than it seems at first as you need to consider both ends of the connection.

You can combine multiple lower bandwidth connections as you suggest to provide an aggregated capacity at your WiFI access point, but you need to remember that the back end will still see multiple individual connections. So if you have a single server that you are trying to receive a single large stream from, it will see multiple smaller connections instead of a single large one.

You can get round this by adding some functionality on the server side to 'bind' or 'bond' the individual streams and make them appear as a single large connection to your server but you usually need a service from your ISP or some specialist 'bonding' provider to achieve this.

See the very good discussion and links in the answer below on Superuser for more information:

- https://superuser.com/questions/660798/merging-two-incoming-broadband-lines-for-faster-internet